# Multiple times method calling from angular template

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular9, rxjs-observables

I am using method inside a template to call the function, that returns `boolean` value. The issue is that the function is called more than 6 times. After that I used `changeDetectionStrategy.onPush`  which reduced the calls to 2 times. Below is my code

**HTML**

```
<div *ngIf="(checkboolObs(check$)) | async"></div>
```

**TS**

```
check$: Observable<service> = this.data.getresponse();

ngOnInit() {
  this.checkboolObs();
}
checkboolObs(style):boolean {
  return somestyleIDS.includes(style.component)
}
```

If the value is found it returns `true`, but it is called several times i need to call it only once. The reason behind this is because `checkboolobs()` is not triggered some times while navigating that's why I am calling this method from the template.

Comment: I don't see any connection of the Observable `check$` and the rest of the code. `checkboolObs` is not an observable

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm pls check now

Comment: Still, you use the async pipe on `checkBoolObs` which return a `boolean` and not `Observable<boolean>`. I don't get how `check$` is involved in here. Additionally maybe this article will help you https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal as every time the change-detection cycle is called it will evaluate the template and your function is part of it, so the function will be re-evaluated(called again).

A brief explanation of how does the change detection work in Angular

Imagine that each time there is an event, that might cause any change (for example clicks, some time intervals are doing something, ajax calls) Angular takes the template and re-evaluates it for you out of the box (in other words updates the HTML).

When you use the `onPush` strategy you are basically telling angular to stop listening for any of the mentioned changes because you will be the one in charge of telling the framework when a change has occurred.
** Disclaimer we have the `| async` that can be used in templates and it will work fine with the `onPush` strategy and if your inputs change by reference change detection will be triggered, but as I said this is a brief explanation.

So the thing that you can do is (i assume that you are getting the ids from the `check$` observable)

```
myCheck$ = this.check$.pipe(map(arrayOfIds => arrayOfIds.includes(style.component)))
```

and then use `myCheck$` inside your template with `|async`.

If this doesn't work please explain in more detail your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Another template only alternative that would work with your typescript code:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="check$ | async as check">
  <div *ngIf="checkboolObs(check))">...</div>
</ng-container>
```

Here you will only evaluate `check` when the observable returns and that `check` doesn't evaluate to `false` with the help of the `async as` pipe