# Http request starts leaking

Tags: angular, observable

I'm using this code to translate each word with *translateBack*

```
<span *ngFor="let word of getWords(); index as i">
  <button (click)="speak(word)"
  [matTooltip]="translateBack(word) | async">{{word}}</button>
</span>
```

where *translateBack* is

```
translateBack(word: string) {
  const options = {q: word, source: 'ru-RU', target: 'en-GB'};
  return this._http.post(url + key, options).pipe(
    take(1),
    map((res: any) => res.data.translations[0].translatedText)
  )
}
```

but in my console it shows a never-ending log of http requests. How do just take one? (i tried take(1))

Comment: for every buttons in the for loop, you are making an http request it makes sense for the program to make a lot of http requests here. take(1) for an http request is not really useful since a Post/Get request (using the angular-http) returns only once and completes.

Comment: When you call functions and methods from the template they get called on every "tick", too; I'd suggest making `translateBack` into a pipe itself.

Comment: @jonrsharpe is it really on every "tick"? I thought angular updates where things changed after every tick.

Comment: @Jensen see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/64499097/3001761

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @jonrsharpe, does a pipe mean that you avoid rerendering for every tick?

Answer (score 2):

In Angular it's better use forkJoin that make a call in a loop:

Use a forkJoin to translate all the words at time

```
translateWord=forkJoin(this.getWords().map(word=>{
   const options = {q: word, source: 'ru-RU', target: 'en-GB'};
   //I suppose is this.url and this.key
   return this._http.post(this.url + this.key, options).pipe(map(
        (res:any)=>({word:word,translate:res.data.translations[0].translatedText})))
   }
   ))
```

And use

```
<span *ngFor="let word of translateWord|async; index as i">
  <button (click)="speak(word.word)"
  [matTooltip]="word.translate">{{word.word}}</button>
</span>
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks, but I'm getting this typescript error: any
Object is of type 'unknown'.ngtsc(2571) for word.word and word.translate

Comment: ::glups:: I suppose is the this.getWords().map( **x** =>{...} (is this.getWords().map( **word** =>{...} -just corrected in code-