# For angular, is it better to handle logic for dynamic text in html file or in component file?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Hello I am currently working with Angular/TS to dynamically render different pricing cards. I am running into many situations where I need to dynamically render text. Is it better to handle this logic directly in the html?

For example:

```
            <h1>
              {{ option.frequency === "YEARLY" ? ("YEARLY") : ("MONTHLY") }}
            </h1>
```

Or is it better to handle the logic in the component itself. Something like:

```
            <h1>
              {{ getFrequency(option) }}
            </h1>
```

Comment: I think, if its something simple like comparing/checking a variable value, use it in HTML. Like for this case you've shared. If it something complex, like filtering/mapping arrays or any other operatoin which requires other checks and all, use in ts.

Comment: It would be better to use it in template itself as it will avoid calling the getFrequency function on every change

Answer (score 1):

Best approach in your case is Pure Pipe. Template expression or function/getter will be triggered in any change detection cycle.

Another idea to read your code easily. For that case you should use readable names like `{{ option.frequency | yearlyOrMonthly }}`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use in template, if the operation is a simple one, like comparing/checking variables (as in your case). Because everytime the change-detection cycle is called it will evaluate the template and will call your function again and again.
But for cases having a complex logic, use in component.
Some good reads are

1. [Multiple times method calling from angular template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64499097/multiple-times-method-calling-from-angular-template)
2. https://medium.com/emoteev-blog/call-functions-in-angular-templates-the-good-way-f025f65b0e55
3. https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496

Comment: Also, another good approach can be to put it like this <h1>{{ option?.frequency === "YEARLY" ? ("YEARLY") : ("MONTHLY") }}</h1> so, if option is null or undefined it wont throw exception